# How come God did not give some sign of the grave consequences for all humanity in Genesis 2:17?

Tags: genesis, faith, adam

> Genesis 2:17 You must not eat from the tree of the knowledge of good and evil, for when you eat from it you will certainly die."

Should Adam automatically believe what God said on its face value? Did God require that from Adam? Should Adam ask God for a demonstration or proof?

Comment: I suggest you stop asking about "blind faith" - it's a highly offensive term and is exclusively used pejoratively.

Comment: Why is it offensive?

Comment: Adam had just been created. Out of nothing, he had an existence. Then, the One who created him (for his own purpose) tells him that partaking of a certain something is fatal. He does this out of sheer goodness, advising him of something necessary to his welfare.  You seem to think it is logical for the created one to _immediately disbelieve his Creator._ How odd. This is clearly a matter of your own opinion.

Comment: Adam was not created out of nothing.  He was formed from the dust (Heb: apar) of the soil (Heb: adamah).  He was Adam from the Adamah.  Soil, moisture, and breath of God.  God formed Adam and then gave him life mouth to mouth.

Comment: Adam was made in the image of God, so he knew right from wrong. He knew it was the right thing to obey God.

Comment: @sara By the same logic, Adam was made in the image of God, so he knew good from evil. He knew it was the good thing to obey God.

Comment: Nigel, God did not create Adam out of nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Tony, perhaps you are suggesting that Adam should have been more incredulous towards his creator?  Note that Adam watches *the woman* to see what happens when she eats, so it's not clear that he truly believed, but may have been afraid to act.

Second, Adam didn't know good and bad (see Genesis 3:22 that he "came to know good and bad" - that is, he did not know it before hand).  So it is unclear to me how Adam and the woman (she is not named Eve until later - and name changes MATTER) would know right from wrong.  How would they know it was good or bad to follow the command of God?

To me, this story seems like the inevitability of our condition, not some moral story.  I would say to directly provide my answer to your question:  You ask "should" Adam do *x*.  I answer, "should implies something good/better than what is."  Adam had absolutely no basis for making such a determination, and we are looking back at the story through the delusion of the knowledge of good and bad which Christ was free from (See Matthew's model of Jesus in Isaiah 7:14-15).

> **Isaiah 7:14-15**, Therefore the Lord himself will give you a sign. Look, the virgin is with child and shall bear a son, and shall name him Immanuel. 15 He shall eat curds and honey [in paradise/Eden] **before he knows how to refuse the evil and choose the good.**

Also see:

> Deuteronomy 1:39, "your children, who today do not know **right from wrong**, they shall enter there;"

And Christ repeatedly says that we must be children to enter paradise.

The answer to your question is "no." But not because your question has a yes or no answer, but because your question is broken in an important and fundamental way diagnosed by Christ.

The Japanese have a third answer, "[mu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_(negative))" which means "un-ask."